# Socket API: not allowed in packaged apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use the new [Socket API](https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/apps/socket.html) for Chrome extensions, and I'm encountering a confusing error.  The manifest for my sample app looks like this:

```
{
  "name":"Yet Another Socket App",
  "version":"0.0.1",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "permissions":[
    "experimental", "socket"
  ],
  "app":{
    "launch":{
        "local_path":"index.html"
    }
  }
}
```

The app is loading (i.e., no error alerts), but a warning appears beneath its entry in `chrome://extensions`: `'socket' is not allowed for specified package type (theme, app, etc.).`

**Notes:** `index.html` exists and is a simple HTML document (and `chrome.socket` is indeed `undefined` within it). I have enabled experimental APIs via `chrome://flags`. I am running the Dev channel of Chrome (`v22.0.1229.6 dev`) on Ubuntu.

Is this a momentary hiccup in socket support (this is the Dev channel, after all), or am I setting up my app incorrectly somehow? Also, I had to uninstall Chrome Stable to install Dev; is it possible that `apt-get purge google-chrome-stable` and `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome` was insufficient to clear out every piece of the Stable channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to recreate this example from Google:
http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_network.html

Chrome always said

> Invalid value for 'permissions[1]'

The correct manifest file is available in their sample App:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/udp

After changing `permissions` in `manifest.json` to

```
"permissions": [
    "experimental",
    {"socket": [
        "udp-send-to"
    ]},
    "app.window"
]
```

I can now access the `socket` object in Chrome **version 23 or higher**:

```
var socket = chrome.socket || chrome.experimental.socket;
```

Comment: Indeed, I should have looked at their Github examples first (and I will do so in the future). Thanks!

Comment: @apsillers: This new format for socket permissions landed last week in Canary. Samples were changed but not the docs. Would you mind filling a bug in crbug.com? Thanks!

Comment: Just found out other possible subpermissions than `udp-send-to`: `udp-bind` and `tcp-connect`

Comment: thx @hlidka for your comment, I was looking for the permission of bind `udp-bind` since yesterday